# Table size in AWS-Athena

Tags: size, amazon-athena

Is there SQL-based way to retrieve the size of all tables within a database in AWS-Athena?

I'm more familiar with MSSQL and there it is relatively easy to write such query.

Comment: You could use in Hive the following command below, but Athena doesn't support it. show tblproperties <table_name>("rawDataSize") In my opinion you can only check the size of the bucket on s3 which you use.

Answer (score 3):

The quick way is via s3:  `... > Show Properties > Location` and lookup the size in the s3-console.

**Explainer**

You can run `SELECT * FROM some_table` for each table and look at the result metadata for the amount scanned, but it will be an expensive way to do it.

Athena doesn't really know about the data in your tables the way an RDBMS does, it's only when you query a table that Athena goes out to look at the data. It really S3 that you should as. You can list all objects in the location(s) of your tables and sum their sizes, but that might be a time consuming way of doing it if there are many objects.

The least expensive, and least time consuming way, when there are many hundreds of thousands of objects, is to enable S3 Inventory on the bucket that contains the data for your tables, then use the inventory to sum up the sizes for each table. You can get the inventory in CSV, ORC, or Parquet format, and they all work well with Athena – so if you have a lot of files in your bucket you can still query the inventory very efficiently.

You can read more about S3 Inventory here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html